# Publish World topographic map to arcgis server

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-online-basemaps

I need to publish esri World topographic map to arcgis server but I got this error
"Layer type is not supported" in the arcmap

Url to the original map
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot publish a basemap which is an ArcGIS Server service itself. You need to add the basemap Topo to your web application or some other client from which you want to access your GIS services.

From the [Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00sq00000049000000):

> Your data frame contains a basemap layer. Basemap layers contain
>   layers or map services meant to be used as a background or reference
>   point for other layers in your map. Generally, these layers should be
>   published as separate map services and mashed up with your operational
>   layers in a web map.

Comment: But I can publish the mxd directly to the arcgis server using server's interface..But can't publish using the arcmap or using python script.

Comment: No, you can't. In order to publish via AGS Manager, you need .sd file. To create .sd file in ArcMap, you would need to resolve the errors such as that you have. No basemap layers in a map service.

Comment: I'm sure I'm publishing it to the server using arcgis server manager.